# Android app will not open once installed from the market

Tags: android, google-play

I have built a small android application.

I have successfully tested it on the emulator. I installed the APK directly on my phone, and it worked perfectly. I then placed it on the market, and it installed flawlessly but... it will not open from the market (open is disabled), it has not created an app shortcut in the home, as it did when I installed my local APK.

It only offers the uninstall functionality. Uninstalling and installing yields the same result.

For those that would care to check out what on earth happens when they install the blasted thing, my simple application is called BMI Assistant, and the author (me) is Jorge de Abreu.

And no, I'm in no way trying to boost my app download count. The blasted thing would only tarnish my reputation, if anything. It actually won't do squat once installed from the market :)

Comment: please provide some code of your activity/manifest file.

Comment: good way to increase your app's downloads :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw line in your code:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:enabled="false">
```

Change attribute *android:enabled* to **true** and you get what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't defined any activity as the main action (whereas in the IDE you maybe launch the activity by explicitly choosing one in the IDE startup options?). Make sure one activity has

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

in the manifest.

Comment: Hmm.. I believe I saw that one before. Though it might have been when I was perusing some samples. Will look into it as soon as I get home and baby stops nagging about wanting a bellyfull of grub.

Comment: Hmmm... however, if that was the case, should it also not run when directly installed from the apk, without going through the marketplace? Because it works flawlessly in this situation.